# Rsync delete issue

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, cron, bash-scripting

I implemented `rsync` to backup the data from the server to my local machine,and done it regularly by `cron`. It works fine but yesterday it deletes the files from the folders on my local machine but on server the files exist.

Kindly tell me what the problem behind this scenario.

My `rsync` command:

```
rsync -avhe --progress --delete $source $destination
```

Comment: Have you made any changes between yesterday and when it last ran as expected?

Comment: No changes on server and local machine from 2 days. It just update the error logs and take some database backup files.

Comment: What do the error logs say?

Comment: Where can I find error logs? I checked the cron logs, they was fine.